# Understanding Node.JS async.parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing

I need to request data from two web servers. The tasks are independent; therefore, I am using [aync.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async). Now I am only writing 'abc', 'xyz', and 'Done' to the body of my web page.

Since tasks are performed at the same time, can I run into a strange output? E.g.,

```
xab
cyz
```

**The code.**

```
var async = require('async');

function onRequest(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type" : "text/plain"
    });

    async.parallel([ function(callback) {
        res.write('a');
        res.write('b');
        res.write('c\n');
        callback();
    }, function(callback) {
        res.write('x');
        res.write('y');
        res.write('z\n');
        callback();
    } ], function done(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.end("\nDone!");
    });

}

var server = require('http').createServer(onRequest);
server.listen(9000);
```

Comment: The order of what is written to `res` is dependant on which of the async.parallel task finishes first but as the tasks are independent than the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Bulkan, thank you. But `parallel` seems not to work properly. Please read [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186787/node-js-async-parallel-doesnt-wait-until-all-the-tasks-have-completed).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you want to be absolutely certain in the order in which the results are printed, you should pass your data (`abc\n` and `xyz\n`) through the [callbacks](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) (first parameter is the error) and handle/write them in the final `async.parallel` callback's `results` argument.

```
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'abc\n');
    },
    two: function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'xyz\n');
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    // results now equals to: results.one: 'abc\n', results.two: 'xyz\n'
});
```

Comment: I can pass the arguments, but I should perform long operations within the parallel functions

Comment: I was assuming you were doing some long operation to get the two strings (maybe from a database), suggesting separating the code for retrieving data (parallel) and processing (`res.write`) it (sequential).

Comment: Strange conversation you have here, guys. Did Michael Tang gave correct answer? Not clear

Comment: @Green I think some of the comments were lost... basically what I meant was that the writing of the data to the console is something one wants to be synchronized, and thus should be executed in the `parallel`'s callback. The functions in the first argument to `parallel` should be in charge of getting any data (that can be done asynchronously in any order) and collecting it for `parallel`'s callback. In this case we're calling `parallel` with trivial functions, but one can imagine reading from disk or the network in its place.