# Node.JS async.parallel doesn't wait until all the tasks have completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, progress-bar, node-async

I am using [aync.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async) to run two functions in parallel. The functions request RSS feeds. Then the RSS feeds are parsed and added to my web page.

But for some reason `async.parallel` runs the callback method without waiting until the two functions have completed

[The documentation says:](https://github.com/caolan/async)

> Once the tasks have completed, the results are passed to the final
>   callback as an array.

**My code.**

```
require('async').parallel([ function(callback) {
        fetchRss(res, bbcOpts); // Needs time to request and parse
        callback();
    }, function(callback) {
        // Very fast.
        callback();
    } ], function done(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.end("Done!");
    });
```

In fact I only have "Done!" on my web page. Why?

Why do I need to call `res.end()`?

The [Node.JS documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding) says:

> The method, response.end(), MUST be called on each response.

If I don't call it, my web page will be being "downloaded" (I mean a progress bar in the address line of my browser).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose your `fetchRss` function is asynchronous: is is performed later and the callback is immediately called. You should send the callback to `fetchRss`:

```
function fetchRss(res, bbcOpts, callback) {
    doSomething();
    callback();
}

require('async').parallel([ function(callback) {
        fetchRss(res, bbcOpts, callback); // Needs time to request and parse
    }, function(callback) {
        // Very fast.
        callback();
    } ], function done(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.end("Done!");
    });
```

---

On a side note, you should call `res.end()` in order for Node to know that the message is complete and that everything (headers + body) has been written. Otherwise, the socket will stay open and will wait forever for another message (which is why the browser shows a progress bar: it doesn't know that the request has ended).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **async.reflect** or **async.reflectAll** to do make sure all functions are completed
http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#reflect