# modified array of object property then pass to front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node (express) and want to add a new property before my response (in here I named it as result) get passed to the front-end.

```
async.parallel(stack, function (err,result) {
  result.users[0].price = 100
  // console.log(result.users[0]); // I couldn't find price property here I wonder why.
  res.json(result);
});
```

Why is this so?

I tried to alter the other property like password:

```
console.log(delete result.users[0].password);
console.log(result.users[0]) // password is still present here?
```

I tried a mini example in fiddle it worked. https://jsfiddle.net/16333z15/

Comment: what does the returned `result` look like? have you logged that?

Comment: @BennettAdams yes, it doesn't have the price property.

Comment: And what's `async.parallel` doing here, what exactly is asynchronous, and where are you trying to use it ?

Comment: @adeneo my full code. http://pastebin.com/5xj5Z8hh

Comment: Too complicated for me, looks like you're using MongoDB and doing some async calls to the DB, but I really don't understand how passing the enitre `stack` object to `async.parallel(stack...` would work ?

Comment: Look at the answer here and u will know how async parallel work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186081/understanding-node-js-async-parallel

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/json', function (req, res) {
    var result = {
        users: [{
            id: 1,
            name: "abc"
        }]
    };
    result.users[0].price = 100;
    res.json(result);
});
```

I have tried this in express and it's worked. You should check the **result** type, I think it's not **tuple**.

Comment: I found the problem is using async, damn it this npm behave strangely, it doesn't give me the power to alter the response.